# How to format current date and hour with Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

With Twig 3 and twig-intl :

- `dump(date('now'))` return current DateTime object : **good** ;
- `dump(date('now')|format_date('full'))` return string date : **good** ;
- `dump(date('now')|format_date('full', 'none'))` return empty string `""` ; why ?
- `dump(date('now')|format_date('full', 'short'))` return strange string `"118"` or `"348" or`"578"`, ... ; why ?

I don't understand why I can't display the current date and time (full, short).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing [format_date()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_date.html) and [format_datetime()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_datetime.html) functions.

- The format_date() documentation says "It behaves in the exact same way as the format_datetime filter, but without the time."
- The format_datetime() documentation says it allows a second argument none|short|medium|long|full for the time, wich does not exist for the format_date function.

> dump(date('now')|format_date('full', 'none')) return empty string "" ;
>   why ?

=> Because the second argument is not correct. Possible arguments are types dateFormat, locale and pattern.

> dump(date('now')|format_date('full', 'short')) return strange string
>   "118" or "348" or"578"`, ... ; why ?

=> For the same reason.

> I don't understand why I can't display the current date and time
>   (full, short).

=> Use format_datetime() instead :

```
{{ date('now')|format_datetime('full', 'none') }}
{{ date('now')|format_datetime('full', 'short') }}
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: oh thank you i used autocompletion from my editor without realizing that i had selected the wrong function